# Profile image not showing after saving it, it just shows a white blank screen

Tags: java

After I save my profile image it says image updated but when I open settings again it does not show any image; instead, a white screen. It shows the status though.

Here is my code:

```
private Button UpdateAccountSettings;
private EditText userName, userStatus;
private CircleImageView userProfileImage;

private String currentUserID;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference Rootref;
private static final int GalleryPick = 1;
private StorageReference UserProfileImagesRef;

private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    Rootref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    UserProfileImagesRef= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");

    InitializeFields();

    userName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    UpdateAccountSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            UpdateSettings();
        }
    });


    RetrieveUserInfo();

    userProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GalleryPick);
        }
    });

}



private void InitializeFields() {
    UpdateAccountSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_settings_button);
    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_user_name);
    userStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_status );
    userProfileImage= (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_image );
    loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode== GalleryPick && resultCode== RESULT_OK && data!= null)
    {
        Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(this);
    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            loadingBar.setTitle("set Profile Image");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, your profile image is updating...");
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            loadingBar.show();

            Uri resultUri =  result.getUri();
            StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImagesRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

            filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                   if (task.isSuccessful())
                   {
                       Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this," Profile Image Uploded succesfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                       final String downloadedUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                       Rootref.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("image")
                               .setValue(downloadedUrl)
                               .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                       if (task.isSuccessful())
                                       {
                                           Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Image saved in database Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                           loadingBar.dismiss();

                                       }
                                       else
                                       {
                                           String message = task.getException().toString();
                                           Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                           loadingBar.dismiss();
                                       }
                                   }
                               });
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       String message = task.getException().toString();
                       Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       loadingBar.dismiss();
                   }


                }
            });

        }

    }
}

private void UpdateSettings() {

    String setUserName = userName.getText().toString();
    String setStatus = userStatus.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(setUserName)){

        Toast.makeText(this,"Please write your username first..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(setStatus)){

        Toast.makeText(this,"Please write your Status first..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else {
        HashMap<String, String> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
        profileMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
        profileMap.put("name", setUserName);
        profileMap.put("Status", setStatus);

        Rootref.child("Users").child(currentUserID).setValue( profileMap)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            SendUserToMainActivity();

                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile  Updated Succesfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                        else {
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,    "Error:" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }


                    }
                });
    }
}

private void RetrieveUserInfo()
{
    Rootref.child("Users").child(currentUserID)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    if((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name") ) &&(dataSnapshot.hasChild("image")))

                    {
                        String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        String retrievesStatus = dataSnapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString();
                        String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                        userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                        userStatus.setText(retrievesStatus);
                        Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);

                    }
                    else if((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name")))
                    {
                        String retrieveUserName = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue()).toString();
                        String retrievesStatus = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("Status").getValue()).toString();


                        userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                        userStatus.setText(retrievesStatus);
                    }
                    else{

                        userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Please set & update your profile information...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


}



private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
}
}
```

My logcat does not show any error, please help me.

Comment: From this method `RetrieveUserInfo()` check `retrieveProfileImage` is imageUrl found or not?

Comment: imageUrl does  get saved in the firebase database i can see the url there

Comment: Ok, But you should check that `retrieveProfileImage` variable contains url data or not when get user info from firebase. Debug it first.